# rename index with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

```
import datetime
dates_list = ['2015-03-28 10:15:36.560000', '2015-03-28 11:35:17.820000',
           '2015-03-29 13:34:54.380000', '2015-03-29 14:10:41.900000',
           '2015-03-31 16:55:43.680000', '2015-03-31 16:57:58.320000',
           '2015-04-02 18:54:31.480000', '2015-04-02 19:46:46.580000',
           '2015-04-03 20:58:27.940000', '2015-04-03 21:30:05.600000']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,8,9],columns=['value'],index=[datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for date in dates_list])

df.index = df.index.date

df
Out[36]: 
            value
2015-03-28    1.0
2015-03-28    2.0
2015-03-29    3.0
2015-03-29    NaN
2015-03-31    5.0
2015-03-31    6.0
2015-04-02    NaN
2015-04-02    NaN
2015-04-03    8.0
2015-04-03    9.0
```

how can I rename the index so that I have

```
df
Out[36]: 
            value
0    1.0
0    2.0
1    3.0
1    NaN
2    5.0
2    6.0
3    NaN
3    NaN
4    8.0
4    9.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.factorize.html) and select first array by `[0]`:

```
df.index = df.index.factorize()[0]
```

Or [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df.index = df.groupby(level=0).ngroup()
```

---

```
print (df)
   value
0    1.0
0    2.0
1    3.0
1    NaN
2    5.0
2    6.0
3    NaN
3    NaN
4    8.0
4    9.0
```

Comment: with the second solution I get AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ngroup'

Comment: @gabboshow - if check docs, there is `New in version 0.20.2.` so upgrade pandas is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although not as neat we could use unique and create a map.

```
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).map({k:v for v,k in enumerate(df.index.unique())})
```